# composite key not displaying orrecyl on django admin

Tags: python, django

I have an intermediary model betwen "estados" e "listaflor", the flora2estado uses a composite key- and a primary key to trick django not to throw errors at me-.

When i click in one object at django admin i get this error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin/accounts/flora2estado/99/change/
get() returned more than one Flora2Estado -- it returned 5!
```

my models.py

```
class Estados(models.Model):
    estado_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    estado_nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'estados'


class Familia(models.Model):
    familia_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    familia_nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'familia'


class Flora2Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.OneToOneField(Estados, models.DO_NOTHING, )
    especie_id = models.IntegerField()
    flora2estado_id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True)   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flora2estado'
        unique_together = (('estado', 'especie_id'),)
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Flora2Estado)
```

Comment: Composite keys are not supported by Django.

Comment: Well, i know, but there are work arounds, and it seems to be working outside of the item, with inlines i can see perfectly the multiple estates in one item.

Comment: True, but they are not _supported_, that's why admin URLs assume that you only have one primary key column. I still don't understand how you ended up having 5 rows with the same `flora2estado_id` value with an `AutoField` though.

Comment: @Selcuk i got it working before, when i deployed my website and changed things around it became broken, i tried one week straight to fix it...

Comment: You could check my project. I make a virtual primary key field to trick Django, and allow to use tables with composite keys without schema altering - https://viewflow.medium.com/the-django-compositeforeignkey-field-get-access-to-a-legacy-database-without-altering-db-tables-74abc9868026